# Tampermonkey - Replace div max-height

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey

With Tampermonkey I would live to replace the max-height (which is variable) of class `content-inner` to a fixed amount of 4000px.

Examples page:

```
<div class="content-inner" style="max-height: 1228px;">
```

```
<div class="content-inner" style="max-height: 1568px;">
```

Should be replaced for:

```
<div class="content-inner" style="max-height: 4000px;">
```

Comment: `element.style.maxHeight = '4000px';` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to vdegenne:

```
var divs =document.getElementsByClassName("content-inner");
divs=Array.from(divs);
divs.forEach(function(div){
  div.style.maxHeight = '4000px';
 });
```

Comment: You actually don't have to convert `divs` to an array. `NodeList` objects have `forEach` method as well.